# how to stop a ball at a particular number in roulette wheel

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm creating a roulette game in WPF and C#.NET. I spin the wheel successfully but I'm stuck to get the specific value where the ball is stopping.

can anybody help me what kind of logic I can apply to get the value of either

I've created basic animation using Expression Blend (code below) how can I get the value where the ball is stopped.

```
 <Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="demo.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="spinWheel">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-0.056"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-89.871"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="-179.468"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="-269.405"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="-360.488"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:3.96" Source="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M39.5,115 C39.5,218.55339 -44.446609,302.5 -148,302.5 C-251.55339,302.5 -335.5,218.55339 -335.5,115 C-335.5,11.446609 -251.55339,-72.5 -148,-72.5 C-44.446609,-72.5 39.5,11.446609 39.5,115 z"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:3.96" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M39.5,115 C39.5,218.55339 -44.446609,302.5 -148,302.5 C-251.55339,302.5 -335.5,218.55339 -335.5,115 C-335.5,11.446609 -251.55339,-72.5 -148,-72.5 C-44.446609,-72.5 39.5,11.446609 39.5,115 z"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource spinWheel}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Margin="22,62,248,26" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse1" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" Height="354" Width="354"/>
        <Path Data="M308,44 L308,394.5" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Width="1" Height="351.5" Canvas.Left="179" Canvas.Top="1"/>
        <Path Data="M144,240 L495.5,240" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="1" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Left="1" Canvas.Top="176.5" Width="352.5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="one" Height="88" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="1" Width="72" FontSize="64" Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="64.5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="two" Height="88" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="2" Width="72" FontSize="64" Canvas.Left="219" Canvas.Top="64.5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="three" Height="88" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="3" Width="72" FontSize="64" Canvas.Left="219" Canvas.Top="200.5"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="four" Height="88" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="4" Width="72" FontSize="64" Canvas.Left="75" Canvas.Top="200.5"/>
    </Canvas>
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="#FFFF2300" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="24" Margin="0,112,264,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="24" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did you consider doing it the other way? Calculate the target number and then take care of the visualization of the ball landing there.

Comment: @Morothar, even if that's not an answer by itself, I'd +1 it if it were posted as an answer (as well as flagging it ;-)

Comment: @Morothar I had thought about that but still having similar problem as to how to stop the ball on particular location

Comment: @HenkHolterman I wish I could ;)

Comment: +1 Morothar's spot on.  You need to programmatically determine the landing position based upon the number you need to land on.  One example would be 36 endpoints representing your numbers; your programatic animation just needs to be smart enough to know where it is going to end, animate realistically to that end and know it's trigger / start position.  From this you can just tell the controller the number you want to land on, allow the animation to hit the start position and gracefully animate into the final position.

Answer (score 0):

Add an event handler on your storyboard

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="spinWheel" Completed="Storyboard_Completed">
```

Add names to your rotate transforms

```
    <RotateTransform x:Name="wheelAngle" />
```

In code behind do some maths and work out where the ball is from `wheelAngle.Angle` and `ballAngle.Angle`.